# How to get inputs with array name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just I want to get the inputs with name like this: name[], and just append to formdata the this kind inputs (name[]) with values.
P.D. Sorry for my bad english, it´s not my native language

```
<input name="name[]" type="text" value="1"></input>
<input name="name[]" type="text" value="2"></input>
<input name="name[]" type="text" value=""></input>
```

In this case, just to apped to formdata first and second inputs
name[]=1,2

Comment: What trouble are you having writing this yourself?  We want to help you learn to do this.  Not do it entirely for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to retrieve the given inputs:

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`input[name='name[]']`)));
```

```html
<input name="name[]" type="text" value="1"></input>
<input name="name[]" type="text" value="2"></input>
<input name="name[]" type="text" value=""></input>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. Excellent solution